# Trace optimization of a function of a left stochastic matrix

Tags: optimization, matrix-calculus, trace

I'm trying to find

$\max_X \text{tr}(AYBX^T)$,

where $A$ is $m \times m$, $B$ is symmetric $n \times n$, and $X$ and $Y$ are $m \times n$ left stochastic matrices. I'm specifically interested when this occurs for $X = Y$. I attempted using a Lagrangian with the constraints $XX^T - J = 0$ or $X^T1_m - 1_n = 0$.

$\mathcal{L} = \text{tr}(AYBX^T) - \text{tr}(\Lambda^T (XX^T - J)) \implies \partial_X \mathcal{L} = AYB - (\Lambda + \Lambda^T)X = 0$,

$\mathcal{L} = \text{tr}(AYBX^T) - \lambda^T(X^T1_m - 1_n) \implies \partial_X \mathcal{L} = AYB - 1_m \lambda^T = 0$,

but those don't seem to work (I know this because I know the answers to some examples). I'm probably doing something wrong that's quite basic, so my apologies. Does anyone have any hints or recommendations?

Thank you very much.

Comment: In the 2nd Lagrangian you are missing the nonnegativity constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $C=AYB$ and consider the function
$$ \phi = {\rm tr}(CX^T) = C:X $$
where a colon denotes the Frobenius product, a convenient notation for the trace. It can also be written as elementwise/Hadamard multiplication followed by summation over all terms.
$$\phi = \sum_{ij}(C\odot X)_{ij}$$

To minimize $\phi$ find the smallest element in each column of $C$ and set the corresponding element of $X$ equal to one. Set all other elements of $X$ to zero.

To maximize $\phi$, locate the largest element in each column of $C$ and set the corresponding element of $X$ equal to one.

The described $X$ matrices are obviously stochastic and maximize (or minimize) the given objective function.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to work out what you'd written before, since it didn't seem to match with my examples. From it, I realized that I'd missed a further constraint

$I \odot ((A - I^\dagger A)XBX^T) \geq 0$.

However, this makes sense from what I asked.

Comment: @Hruodland What is the $I$ matrix in your constraint? Is it the identity matrix, or something else?

Comment: $I$ is the identity, and $I^\dagger$ is the backward identity.

Comment: I can use the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions for this. When the KKT multiplier, $\mu$, is 0, we can just use what you wrote above. Else, let $g = I \odot ((A - I^\dagger A)XBX^T) = 0$, and find $\partial_X \text{tr}(\phi - \mu g) = 0$.